# liquibase - how to change default type for column

Tags: java, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

Is there a way to force liquibase into using different db type for a column of generic type?

I've seen this:
[Force Liquibase to map Blob to BYTEA on PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388886/force-liquibase-to-map-blob-to-bytea-on-postgresql)
and it's not what I would like to do, since changelog is generated by maven plugin, and I like it that way better since there's no overhead for developers (no need to edit it)

Is there a way to register/override types in liquibase for specified database without editing changelog itself?

Example:
mysql: we get datetime instead of explicit datetime(6) or bit(1) instead of tinyint(1)

Comment: You can do that, some folks write extensions or submit a PR to liquibase to change functionality.  If you are able to do that, this guide will help: https://liquibase.jira.com/wiki/spaces/LB/pages/1274904896/How+to+Contribute+Code+to+Liquibase+Core. Or you can put in a request to have the liquibase community look at this: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues

Comment: thanks for reminding me. i've solved the issue - i will write a response with some code in a free moment

Comment: Thanks Miron for helping me in my attempt to organize and clean out some of these liquibase questions on SO.

Comment: @MironBalcerzak Can you please post your solution here. It would be more helpful. Thanks !